# PHP 7 - Class 'Memcached' not found after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 artful

Tags: php, php7

I'm getting:

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)**

**Class 'Memcached' not found**

After upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10.

The code calling memcached:

```
/**
 * Get a new Memcached instance.
 *
 * @return \Memcached
 */
protected function getMemcached()
{
    return new Memcached;
}
```

I tried re-installing php-memcached with --purge.
A look at the output of phpinfo() shows this line:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
```

The memcached.so module has moved from **/usr/lib/php/20151012**
to **/usr/lib/php/20160303**

The answer might be to upgrade to PHP 7.1. Trying that now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to upgrade to PHP 7.1.
The Ubuntu upgrade only does a partial upgrade of PHP from 7.0 to 7.1 when upgrading from 17.04 zesty to 17.10 artful.

After upgrading all your PHP modules to 7.1:

Stop and disable PHP 7.0 FPM

```
sudo systemctl stop php7.0-fpm.service
sudo systemctl disable php7.0-fpm.service
```

Start PHP 7.1 FPM

```
sudo systemctl start php7.1-fpm.service
```

Remember to also fix your web server.
For NGINX I had to change this line:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

Then restart NGINX

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Comment: Had the same issue with Memcached when upgrading from php7.2fpm to php7.3fpm on ubuntu 18.04 with different PPA. This was also the solution.